# how to keep data between two vertical lines in excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to exclude the data before and after the vertical line `|`  and keep only the data between them. Since I need to keep only the data between the first vertical line `|`  and second vertical line `|`, if I use `*|` in the find column and click on the replace all, it removing the data in the middle (doing opposite of what I need). Any help would be appreciated on how to approach this.

Each line is a row in the excel.

**Sample data in excel:**

```
san-diego-22 | AWS clusters1 | P-12313123
america.ls.office | kafka version is not matched | P-34522
sso@email.com | VM is not responding | P-123123
projects/pos@gmail.com/accounts/iap-232434.com/vault/3f4s234234234wd2342342
```

**Output**

```
AWS clusters1
kafka version is not matched
VM is not responding
projects/pos@gmail.com/accounts/iap-232434.com/vault/3f4s234234234wd2342342
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the logic to include the last line in the output (projects...). I assume each line in the sample data in excel represents a row in excel. Please confirm

Comment: Excel 2007/2010? That's pretty ancient. Did you maybe meant another version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do what you want:

```
=IFERROR(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            A1,
            LEFT(A1,FIND("|",A1)+1),
            ""),
        RIGHT(
            SUBSTITUTE(
                A1,
                LEFT(A1,FIND("|",A1)+1),
                ""),
            LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,
                LEFT(A1,
                FIND("|",A1)+1),""))- 
                FIND("|",
                    SUBSTITUTE(A1,                    
                        LEFT(A1,FIND("|",A1)+1),
                        ""))+2),
    ""),
 A1)
```

In Office 365 you would be able to spill it with:

`=BYROW(A1:A4, LAMBDA(r,IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(r,"|"),,2),r)))`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you could try:

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1` --> **MS365 Users Only**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("*",,A1:A4)," | ","*"),,2),A1:A4)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `B15` --> **MS365 Users Only**

```
=BYROW(A1:A4,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(x," | ")," | "),x)))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `B8` --> **Excel 2010+ Onwards**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" | ",A1)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," | ",REPT(" ",100)),100,100)),A1)
```

---

One more way as suggested by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir using `FILTERXML()`

[image]

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()<3][last()]")
```

---

**Note:** The first 2 formulas will spill, hence no need to drag while the last two you need to fill down.

Comment: I like the text before/textafter solution. Never used them before.

Comment: Could be worth adding `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()<3][last()]")` as some 2013 inbetween solution.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, added. I love `FILTERXML()` very smart function indeed.